# extract epoch causes data overlapping postgres

Tags: c, database, postgresql

I'm working with postgres trying to extract the epoch time from a column that is a timestamp

this is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION epochtime(sampleid integer, starttime timestamp without time zone, stoptime timestamp without time zone)
 RETURNS text AS
$BODY$DECLARE
result text;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO result string_agg(concat_ws(',',epochres), ',')
FROM (
Select extract('epoch' from "Timestamp") as epochres from "Results" 
where "SampleID"=sampleid and "Timestamp" >= starttime 
and "Timestamp" <= stoptime order by "Timestamp" asc ) res;

return result;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

C function where the stored procedure is being called:

```
static int getEpoch(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj *const     
objv[]){
Tcl_Obj *result;
char sampleid[15];
char repStartTime[256];
char repStopTime[256];
int length;
int lengthTwo;
int lengthThree;

if (objc != 4) {
    Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, objv, "number of argument error");
    return TCL_ERROR;
}
strcpy(sampleid, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[1], &lengthThree));
strcpy(repStartTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[2], &length));
strcpy(repStopTime, Tcl_GetStringFromObj(objv[3], &lengthTwo));

char command[256];
PQclear(res);
strcpy(command, "Select \"epochtime\"('");
strcat(command, sampleid);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStartTime);
strcat(command,"','");
strcat(command, repStopTime);
strcat(command, "')");
res = PQexec(conn,command);
result = Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
Tcl_SetStringObj(result, PQgetvalue(res,0,0), strlen(PQgetvalue(res,0,0)));
return TCL_OK;
```

}

for small number of data i would say around 700 numbers it works fine, but if i try to get a lot of numbers like 10000 or something like that it causes a segmentation fault in the program and if i run the query within the command line it overlaps all the result, literally the numbers look like they are on top of each other

example small amount of records in the column:
[image: Small Amount of Records]

example large amount of records in the column:
[image: Large Amount of Records]

like i said everything works like it should with the small amount of records but i need it to work the same way with the large amount of records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that you concatenate all epochs into a single string and that leads to a buffer overrun when you have many epochs. In other words, when returning many epochs, the resulting string is larger than the allocated memory for the result, leading to the segmentation fault.

The overprinting issue in pgAdmin is just a side effect. pgAdmin is bad with long strings.

A solution would be to simply return the selection of epochs to your C program as individual records and do any concatenation there. You should allocate a string buffer large enough to hold all epochs in a single string, which you could estimate from the number of epochs returned, multiplied by the typical epoch length which appears to be 10 characters in your case (plus the separator and space, obviously, making it 12).

But do you really need to have all epochs in a single string?

Comment: i figure it had to do something about allocated memory i just never thought that postgres would run out of it, I was doing it that way because of the performance if i do one by one on c it takes way longer than having everything formatted in a way that it would be a list for a blt chart so i would just call the store procedure and would go directly to the graph already formatted. The weird thing is that i use this mechanism in other parts and that has never happened even with a large amount of data.